# Is it possible to synchronization real time date from source to destination?

Tags: rsync, synchronization

We want to copy ~800GB of data from a source server to destination server using rsync. I was wondering if its safe to use rsync without shutting down source server application? Can rsync handle real time data inflow on source while it copies/syncs the data back to destination server?

Answer (score 1):

For backups and real-time synchronization I use `glusterfs`. Is a very friendly and robust sync & backup package.

See more about `glusterfs` in [here](http://gluster.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Quick-Start-Guide/Quickstart/).

Answer (score 1):

Rsync "handles" it by ignoring it. Does that count? Not really... Any changes that get made after rsync copies that portion of the file are lost and not copied. This can mean that different parts of the same file contain data from different points in time.

As you suspected, this can be a problem.

A workaround I often use on linux (saw your tag) is to create an LVM snapshot, mount that read-only, then copy the snapshot data. An LVM snapshot is guaranteed to be unchanging for the lifetime of the snapshot, but it must be sized to hold enough of the changed data (writes.) When an LVM snapshot fills, it becomes unavailable.

For example:

```
# lvcreate --snapshot /dev/vgName/lvName --size 1G --name snapNameDate
# mkdir /snaps
# mkdir /snaps/lvName/Mount/Point
# mount -o ro /dev/vgName/snapNameDate /snaps/lvName/Mount/Point
# cd /snaps/lvName/Mount/Point
# rsync --archive --verbose --progress . user@destination:/destination/Point/.
# cd /
# umount /snaps/lvName/Mount/Point
# lvremove /dev/vgName/snapNameDate
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we have to copy data from a VFS shared drive which does not support taking snapshot of it :(
Hence rsync seems to be the only way out at the moment.

Comment: Isn't VFS just an abstraction layer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system)? What is underneath the VFS that's actually storing your data? Note that any process that read at the file level will have the same problem as rsync does with getting different data at different times out of the same changing file, this includes `cp`, `dd`, `tar`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your inputs!
I totally agree with your point on VFS but we have external team internally which manages the same and taking a snapshot is under their realms.

Comment: On rsync, I did one mock test to copy about 500MB of data from source server to destination server using "rsync -av --progress --sparse"  but was little surprised by the fact that the destination server directory size is much bigger (about 574 MB)than actual source directory data (500MB).
Could this be due to sparse files at destination? If Yes, is there any impact of having sparse files on application? Any way to suppress those sparse files (if that is at first the reason)

ls | wc -l on both directories are giving up same number of files.

Comment: The `--sparse` (`-S`) flag will help if it really is due to sparse files. The only impact you'll have with non-sparse files is the increase in disk allocation. (You can recover the sparseness with `cp` or `rsync` at a later date, when copying to another medium.)

Comment: It makes me believe now that it is not the sparse files now. I tried to add -H also for avoiding hard links but even that did not help. I am not sure what else could be going extra in the target directory. Any idea? Unfortunately, I can not do a "diff" because it takes a lot longer.